# Error when importing xsl files via '<xsl:import ..>' or '<xsl:include ..>' on a 'MS 2012 R2 Server'

Tags: c++, xml, xslt, msxml

If I use `<xsl:include href="Book.xsl">` in document in a very simple command line C++ application, based upon the fantastic C++ MSXML I can't get `xsl:import` or `xsl:include` to work, the program throws the following error on a 'MS 2012 R2 Server'.

> The procedure entry point HttpOpenDependencyHandle could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll

Testing the same command line exe with the same XSL and XML files on Win10 professional and it all works just fine.

If I remove the `<xsl:include href="Book.xsl"/>` line, there's no error but obviously there's no output.

I've built the test application in MSVC 2015.

Checks/Tried:

- MSXML6 present on the server
- Elevating test application with administrator rights
- Changing application to another compatibility mode.
- Run 'Depends' on the test application and on 'Win server 2012 R2' and there  doesn't appear to be anything wrong.
- Absolute paths in xsl import and or include statements
- Tried re-registering C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll that said it had succeed.
- Searching for HttpOpenDependencyHandle clues in Google

Comment: You may have better luck asking this on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Will do. Many thanks for the advise.